# Javascript: change style of some specific element under an id

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my html code:

```
<div class='row' id='row_1'>  
  <span></span><div style='display: inline-block;'></div>
  <span></span><div style='display: inline-block;'></div> 
  <span></span><div style='display: inline-block;'></div>   
</div>
```

I want to change css property only the `<div>` tag or `<span>` tag under the `id='row_1'` If I use `document.getElementById("row_1")` such as:

```
document.getElementById("row_1").style.backgroundColor = color_code;
```

It changes background-color of eveything under `row_1` id. But i want to change css property of a specific tag like `<div>` or `<span>`. How can i do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

Comment: Or [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this helps you...

```js
var nodes = document.getElementById('row_1').getElementsByTagName("span");
for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].style.background = 'red';
}
```

```html
<div class='row' id='row_1'>  
  <span>1</span><div style='display: inline-block;'></div>
  <span>2</span><div style='display: inline-block;'></div> 
  <span>3</span><div style='display: inline-block;'></div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with simple `css` without any `javascript`

```
#row_1 > span {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
var your_div = document.getElementById('row_1');
var childNode = your_div.childNodes[1];
childNode.style.background = 'red';
```

```html
<div class='row' id='row_1'>  
  <span>hello</span><div style='display: inline-block;'></div>
  <span>hi</span><div style='display: inline-block;'></div> 
  <span>thank you</span><div style='display: inline-block;'></div>   
</div>
```

Hope it helps. :)